# Initializing an extended generic property in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, class, generics, typescript-generics

I'm attempting to create a class with a generic parameter that extends type `boolean`. I've tried to make this generic parameter accessible at runtime by assigning it to a property like so:

```
class Example<T extends boolean> {
    foo: T = true;
}
```

The base class declaration works, but the line initializing `foo` yields the error:

```
Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'boolean' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'boolean'.
```

This doesn't make much sense to me. What other type could T be that extends but does not fall under `true | false`? Why does the possibility that it could be another type prevent it from being initialized as a `boolean`?

Comment: What should `new Example<false>().foo` be?  According to the types it's `false`, but according to your initializer, it's `true`.  That's the problem and why you can't do it.